# Why is GUID attribute needed in the first place?

Tags: .net, com, attributes, guid

What is the necessity for the GUID attribute? why don't just let the compiler handle this automatically?!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the Guid attribute that appears above classes in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760126/what-is-the-guid-attribute-that-appears-above-classes-in-c)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the compiler handled this automatically, you'd end up with one of two situations.

- A new GUID every time you compiled - since GUIDs are supposed to be published, this would fail.
- Collisions - if the GUID was the same every time, based on (say) a Hash of the name, multiple projects would end up using the same GUID for different purposes.

The existing approach - an explicit GUID gives developers the power to control these as required.

---

You only actually need to add a GUID attribute in limited cases - the primary one being for COM interop, if you're using .NET to write a COM object for use by another system. Depending on what kind of project you have, this might be an everyday event - or an annual one.

Answer (score 10):

These are attributes that matter a great deal to COM.  Which was the predecessor of .NET and had its heyday in the nineties, before Java stole the show.  .NET needed to be compatible with COM to have a chance of succeeding.  Or in other words, you needed to be able to write a COM server in a .NET language that a large legacy program could use.

The [ComVisible] attribute ensures that a COM client program can see and use the IEnumerable interface.  Essential to allow the client program to enumerate .NET collections.

The [Guid] attribute is crucial in COM, it identifies an interface.  Which is done by a guid, not a name, to ensure that it is unique across multiple applications written by different programmers.  .NET has this too, but however uses a name to make it easier on humans.  "System.Collections.IEnumerable, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089".

IEnumerable<>, the generic version, doesn't have a [Guid].  Generics are not compatible with COM.  It doesn't much matter these days, not much visible COM around anymore, most of it has been wrapped by friendly .NET classes.  But still very core in Windows, notably in the brand-new WinRT (aka Metro, aka Modern UI, aka UWP).  You don't use that directly either, making COM somewhat like the assembly language of Windows programming.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it (just omit the attribute) but then the compiler will generate a new GUID on each recompile even if the interface has not changed. That's unfortunate because the users of that interface don't know about the change and will retrieve the interface by it's old GUID and will therefore fail to retrieve it.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you want to give certain classes or modules a unique identifier that is constant and hard coded inside your source.

Answer (score 0):

To read this definition you would need to look up the meaning of each of those attributes. The first, [`ComVisibleAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comvisibleattribute.aspx), is described as this:

> Controls accessibility of an individual managed type or member, or of all types within an assembly, to COM.

That tells us that `ComVisible` is something to do with COM, and lets us specify whether a particular type is visible to COM programs. Further down on the page is a link to more details on what the attribute is for and how its used by the type library exporter.

The second, [`GuidAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.guidattribute.aspx), is a bit less helpful at first:

> Supplies an explicit System.Guid when an automatic GUID is undesirable

but again, you have to read the rest of the way down, and you will see another mention of the type library exporter.

Putting these two together, it starts to become clear that these two attributes control how `IEnumerator` is processed when exported to a type library. If you don't know what a type library is, this will probably not mean much to you. If you are not using COM interop, then those attributes can safely be ignored. If you *are* using COM interop, you would need to know the `Guid` to properly access the interface from unmanaged COM code.

Microsoft puts these on every interface definition in case you need them; part of the skill in reading the MSDN pages is to recognize this type of information and know when it isn't any use to you. Now that you know what those two attributes are for, you should be able to figure out if they are relevant to you, and ignore them otherwise.