# What is the Guid attribute that appears above classes in C#?

Tags: c#, com-interop

I've picked up some C# code recently and one of the classes has a Guid attribute present above it. I don't understand what this is or what it's used for.

Can someone give me a rundown of what it is, or just point me in the direction of some articles that give more information about this?

Thanks!

Comment: Does it look like this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.guidattribute.aspx

Comment: Yes, it does look like that. Is there a difference between Guid and GuidAttribute?

Comment: when applying an attribute using "[]" you can leave off the "Attribute" at the end of the type name. It assumes it is there. As such, they are the same.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is the COM identifier that represents the class in question.  The class is designed for COM interop.

Answer (score 11):

You might want to take a look at the ComVisibleAttribute class to learn more about the ways you can make managed classes available to unmanaged code.

The [Guid] is the exact equivalent to the .NET Type.AssemblyQualifiedName.  Like

```
System.Object, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5561934e089
```

With the obvious distinction that the .NET type name is easier to read by a human.  It is necessary to allow a program to discover what DLL needs to be loaded to use a type.  In the .NET case, the assemblies are (usually) found by enumerating the GAC.  It is file based.

COM however uses the registry.  After that assembly whose source code you looked at gets built and registered then you can find back the [Guid] in the registry.  Fire up regedit.exe and navigate to `HKLM\Software\Classes\CLSID\{guid}`.  You'll see the registration key values that the runtime uses to load the CLR and the assembly.

Comment: I am currently playing with exposing my .NET class to COM, and have registered my assembly.  Can you explain why the GUID I have specified by the GuidAttribute would not appear in HKLM\Software\Classes\CLSID\?

Comment: Looking in the wrong place is the typical explanation.  Like `HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID`, the home for 32-bit COM servers.

Answer (score 9):

Guid (Globally unique identifier) is used to identify your component by outside world. When you write a project which is going to be used as COM (Component Object Model) you will have to give a unique name. For this reason you need to apply GUID attribute.

You can read more about it here.

[GUIDAttributeClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.guidattribute.aspx)