# GUID Interface/class decoration

Tags: c#, decorator, guid

When an interface (or class?) is decorated as follows:

```
[Guid("XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXX"),
    InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IName
{

...

}
```

(Where the Xs are placeholders for an actual GUID)

A) What term--if any--describes such a GUID decoration?

B) What is the purpose of such a decoration?

*Note: While the InterfaceType(...) decoration was included, I'm not sure if it relates to the GUID(...) decoration at all.*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760126/what-is-the-guid-attribute-that-appears-above-classes-in-c

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms227637(v=vs.80).aspx