# Reading MSDN pages

Tags: c#, msdn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is GUID attribute needed in the first place?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067538/why-is-guid-attribute-needed-in-the-first-place)

I know this question might seem super easy to all of you (you can assign negative score as many as you want feel free) but I personally don't know how to deal with MSDN pages when I get to this:

```
[ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
[GuidAttribute("496B0ABF-CDEE-11d3-88E8-00902754C43A")]
public interface IEnumerator
```

it says is a COM or component object model attribute which is visible. also it has a unique id attribute. This is confusing and no idea where it comes handy. The rest is easy it is a public interface so I know its title is SYNTAX but not sure how I can find its application.

Can somebody give me some clues how I can read this and what kind of benefit I can get from it?

Comment: See this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067538/why-is-guid-attribute-needed-in-the-first-place